# Transaction log dump - backup log from all database to one Dump file

Tags: sql-server

I am working with some old jobs and I found this code snippet.
I am just wondering why would someone dump transaction log files from `ALL` databases in to one file `TxnLogDump.bak`?

Is this simply to `dump(ignore)` the `transaction log` and `shrink`?

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdevices WHERE name = N'TransactionLogDump')
EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropdevice @logicalname = N'TransactionLogDump'
GO

    EXEC master.dbo.sp_addumpdevice  @devtype = N'disk',
@logicalname = N'TransactionLogDump', 
@physicalname = N'\\BackupServer\Backup_Drive\Temp\TxnLogDump.bak'
    GO

USE DB1 
BACKUP LOG DB1 TO TransactionLogDump
dbcc shrinkfile ('DB1', 2)

USE DB2
BACKUP LOG DB2 TO TransactionLogDump
dbcc shrinkfile ('DB2', 2)

USE DB3
BACKUP LOG DB3TO TransactionLogDump
dbcc shrinkfile ('DB3', 2)

USE DB4
BACKUP LOG DB4TO TransactionLogDump
dbcc shrinkfile ('DB4', 2)

USE DB5
BACKUP LOG DB5TO TransactionLogDump
dbcc shrinkfile ('DB5', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but I suspect someone likely only wanted to manage one backup file without thinking of the consequences if it became corrupted.

This approach *does* backup the TLogs, so you can recover from this backup file.  However, shrinking the log is a bad idea for many reasons (as explained by [Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/) and [Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/07/27/oh-the-horror-please-stop-telling-people-they-should-shrink-their-log-files)).

Comment: The single backup file approach requires one to specify the desired backup using `FILE=` during `RESTORE`.